# How do I select an object with the highest value from each date in an array of NSManagedObjects

Tags: arrays, swift

There are many threads on SO that explain different ways to get the maximum value from an array (map, max(by:), reduce, filteredArrayUsingPredicate). I've also considered constructing an `NSPredicate` to use in with my `fetchRequest`. But I haven't found anything that gives me a clue about how to accomplish a simple thing I'm trying to do.

I have an array of `LiftEvent` `NSManagedObjects` and there can be more than one `LiftEvent` on any given date. I want to get one object per date and I want that object to be the one with the largest oneRepMax value on each date.

Say I have these `LiftEvent` objects in an array with these properties:

```
LiftEvent1.date = "3/1/18"
LiftEvent1.oneRepMax = 200

LiftEvent2.date = "3/2/18"
LiftEvent2.oneRepMax = 210

LiftEvent3.date = "3/2/18"
LiftEvent3.oneRepMax = 220

LiftEvent4.date = "3/3/18"
LiftEvent4.oneRepMax = 205

LiftEvent5.date = "3/3/18"
LiftEvent5.oneRepMax = 225
```

I want to pick out the one with the highest weight value on each date which would give me these:

```
LiftEvent1.date = "3/1/18"
LiftEvent1.oneRepMax = 200

LiftEvent3.date = "3/2/18"
LiftEvent3.oneRepMax = 220

LiftEvent5.date = "3/3/18"
LiftEvent5.oneRepMax = 225
```

I fetch the `LiftEvent`'s and sort them like so:

```
let liftEvents = dataManager.fetchLiftsEventsOfType(liftEventTypeUuid)

var sortedLiftEvents = liftEvents.sorted(by: { $0.date.compare($1.date) == .orderedAscending })
```

But of course when I do this, I get a single `LiftEvent` with the highest `oneRepMax` value:

```
var maxLiftEvent = sortedLiftEvents.max { a, b in a.oneRepMax < b.oneRepMax }
```

How can I get a single `LiftEvent` from each date, each one having the highest `oneRepMax`value on that date and ensure that if there are more than one on a date with the same `oneRepMax` value that I only choose one?

Comment: Use a `[String:LiftEvent]` dictionary to keep track of your best `LiftEvent` for each date.  When adding a new one, check to see if you already have one for this date, and check to see which one has the highest `oneRepMax`.  If new one is higher, replace it in the dictionary.  When you're done, get an array of all of the dictionary values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group all events in a dictionary keyed by date, and get the maximum for every date.

Since your dates can have different hour/minute/second values, you need to unique each date by day, and this can be done by computing the number of days between a given date and Jan 1 1970.

```
let groupedEvents = Dictionary(grouping: liftEvents, by: { floor($0.date.timeIntervalSince1970 / 86400) })
```

This will result in a [Double: [LiftEvent]] dictionary, the key being the number of days since 1970, and the value being the events in that day.

Now that you have all the events grouped by day, you can `map` that dictionary to find the interesting events:

```
let maxEventsPerDay = groupedEvents.map { $1.max(by: { $0.oneRepMax < $1.oneRepMax }) }
```

The result will be an array of events that have the max `oneRepMax` per their date.

Comment: told you already about it `map { $1.max(by: { $0.oneRepMax < $1.oneRepMax }) }` the same principle applies here

Comment: @LeoDabus professional defect, updated :P Though in my defence the `$0.1` version is not incorrect.

Comment: This makes sense and seems like it should work but the map function isn't filtering out any LiftEvents. I end up with as many as I started with. I have this: `let groupedEvents = Dictionary(grouping: liftEvents, by: { $0.date })` `let maxEventsPerDate = groupedEvents.map { $1.max(by: { $0.oneRepMax.value < $1.oneRepMax.value }) }`. `oneRepMax` is a `Measurement<UnitMass>`, if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Jim is it possible that your `date` properties have different values for hours/minutes/seconds? In that case the grouping won't help much. But just to make sure we're on the same page, `date` is of type `Date`, or is it `String` as in the question samples?

Comment: Ah, they're `Date` types. Should I cast them as `String` and somehow lop off that time stamp?

Comment: @Jim thought so :) Please see my updated answer for grouping by day.

Comment: @Cristik, you just saved me countless more hours of searching and taught me a few things. Thanks very much!

Comment: @Cristik even though your answer is correct, I don't think grouping by `TimeInterval` is the best approach, since it involves unnecessary conversions between `Date` and `TimeInterval`, especially if you need to modify the collection later on. You can simply use `Calendar.startOfDay` to map all events corresponding to the same day to a single Dictionary key.

Comment: @DávidPásztor good hint regarding `startOfDay`. About the unnecessary conversions, I don't think I get your point. After all, a `Date` is a wrapper around a time interval.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to group your events by Day. You can do this using `Array.reduce(into:)` to create a Dictionary of type `[Date:[LiftEvent]]`, where you can use `Calendar.current.startOfDay` to group all `Date` objects corresponding to a single day.

Then you can find the maximum event of each day by `Array.max(by:)` easily.

```
let dailyLiftEvents = liftEvents.reduce(into: [Date:[LiftEvent]](), { dailyLiftEvents, currentLiftEvent in
    dailyLiftEvents[Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: currentLiftEvent.date), default: [LiftEvent]()].append(currentLiftEvent)
})
let dailyMaxLiftEvents = dailyLiftEvents.map({$0.value.max(by: {$0.oneRepMax < $1.oneRepMax})})
```